# Add a vertical slider with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, slider

I would like to create a vertical slider widget instead horizontal slider with matplotlib.

I have found a good example in the matplotlib webpage http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html but I do not know how to move the slider in the Y axis and change the slider labels. I can change the position of the axis but not the movement of the slider. The example is here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
a0 = 5
f0 = 3
s = a0*np.sin(2*np.pi*f0*t)
l, = plt.plot(t,s, lw=2, color='red')
plt.axis([0, 1, -10, 10])

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axfreq = plt.axes([0.03, 0.25, 0.03, 0.65], axisbg=axcolor)
axamp = plt.axes([0.08, 0.25, 0.03, 0.65], axisbg=axcolor)
sfreq = Slider(axfreq, 'Freq', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=f0)
samp = Slider(axamp, 'Amp', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=a0)

def update(val):
    amp = samp.val
    freq = sfreq.val
    l.set_ydata(amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
sfreq.on_changed(update)
samp.on_changed(update)

resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')
def reset(event):
    sfreq.reset()
    samp.reset()
button.on_clicked(reset)

rax = plt.axes([0.5, 0.025, 0.15, 0.15], axisbg=axcolor)
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('red', 'blue', 'green'), active=0)
def colorfunc(label):
    l.set_color(label)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
radio.on_clicked(colorfunc)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this post is 5 years old, but after trying to implement my own vertical slider I then found that as of [matplotlib 3.1](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.1.0.html#adjusted-matplotlib-widgets-slider-to-have-vertical-orientation) this feature exists natively.

I have matplotlib `3.1.2` and one of the parameters is

> orientation : str, 'horizontal' or 'vertical', default: 'horizontal'
>   The orientation of the slider.

See here https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/widgets_api.html

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer. Works really well with matplotlib `3.1.3`.

Answer (score 14):

As of matplotlib 3.1 there is an orientation keyword.  Up through matplotlib 3.1 this was not possible out of the box, because the `matplotlib.widgets.Slider` implementation used `axvspan` and `axvline` to define the slider bar (which is a `patches.Polygon`), and updated it according to the horizontal assumption.

If you are still using an older version of matplotlib, it is not too difficult to write your own vertical slider using the horizontal slider as an example (you would likewise subclass from `AxesWidget`), but it has to be done yourself.

**Valid as of matplotlib 2.0:**  A vertical slider class is given below; it works just like the horizontal one, except it is ... well ... vertical!

```
from matplotlib.widgets import AxesWidget
import six

class VertSlider(AxesWidget):
    """
    A slider representing a floating point range.

    For the slider to remain responsive you must maintain a
    reference to it.

    The following attributes are defined
      *ax*        : the slider :class:`matplotlib.axes.Axes` instance

      *val*       : the current slider value

      *hline*     : a :class:`matplotlib.lines.Line2D` instance
                     representing the initial value of the slider

      *poly*      : A :class:`matplotlib.patches.Polygon` instance
                     which is the slider knob

      *valfmt*    : the format string for formatting the slider text

      *label*     : a :class:`matplotlib.text.Text` instance
                     for the slider label

      *closedmin* : whether the slider is closed on the minimum

      *closedmax* : whether the slider is closed on the maximum

      *slidermin* : another slider - if not *None*, this slider must be
                     greater than *slidermin*

      *slidermax* : another slider - if not *None*, this slider must be
                     less than *slidermax*

      *dragging*  : allow for mouse dragging on slider

    Call :meth:`on_changed` to connect to the slider event
    """
    def __init__(self, ax, label, valmin, valmax, valinit=0.5, valfmt='%1.2f',
                 closedmin=True, closedmax=True, slidermin=None,
                 slidermax=None, dragging=True, **kwargs):
        """
        Create a slider from *valmin* to *valmax* in axes *ax*.

        Additional kwargs are passed on to ``self.poly`` which is the
        :class:`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` which draws the slider
        knob.  See the :class:`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` documentation
        valid property names (e.g., *facecolor*, *edgecolor*, *alpha*, ...).

        Parameters
        ----------
        ax : Axes
            The Axes to put the slider in

        label : str
            Slider label

        valmin : float
            The minimum value of the slider

        valmax : float
            The maximum value of the slider

        valinit : float
            The slider initial position

        label : str
            The slider label

        valfmt : str
            Used to format the slider value, fprint format string

        closedmin : bool
            Indicate whether the slider interval is closed on the bottom

        closedmax : bool
            Indicate whether the slider interval is closed on the top

        slidermin : Slider or None
            Do not allow the current slider to have a value less than
            `slidermin`

        slidermax : Slider or None
            Do not allow the current slider to have a value greater than
            `slidermax`


        dragging : bool
            if the slider can be dragged by the mouse

        """
        AxesWidget.__init__(self, ax)

        self.valmin = valmin
        self.valmax = valmax
        self.val = valinit
        self.valinit = valinit
        self.poly = ax.axhspan(valmin, valinit, 0, 1, **kwargs)

        self.hline = ax.axhline(valinit, 0, 1, color='r', lw=1)

        self.valfmt = valfmt
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_ylim((valmin, valmax))
        ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.set_navigate(False)

        self.connect_event('button_press_event', self._update)
        self.connect_event('button_release_event', self._update)
        if dragging:
            self.connect_event('motion_notify_event', self._update)
        self.label = ax.text(0.5, 1.03, label, transform=ax.transAxes,
                             verticalalignment='center',
                             horizontalalignment='center')

        self.valtext = ax.text(0.5, -0.03, valfmt % valinit,
                               transform=ax.transAxes,
                               verticalalignment='center',
                               horizontalalignment='center')

        self.cnt = 0
        self.observers = {}

        self.closedmin = closedmin
        self.closedmax = closedmax
        self.slidermin = slidermin
        self.slidermax = slidermax
        self.drag_active = False

    def _update(self, event):
        """update the slider position"""
        if self.ignore(event):
            return

        if event.button != 1:
            return

        if event.name == 'button_press_event' and event.inaxes == self.ax:
            self.drag_active = True
            event.canvas.grab_mouse(self.ax)

        if not self.drag_active:
            return

        elif ((event.name == 'button_release_event') or
              (event.name == 'button_press_event' and
               event.inaxes != self.ax)):
            self.drag_active = False
            event.canvas.release_mouse(self.ax)
            return

        val = event.ydata
        if val <= self.valmin:
            if not self.closedmin:
                return
            val = self.valmin
        elif val >= self.valmax:
            if not self.closedmax:
                return
            val = self.valmax

        if self.slidermin is not None and val <= self.slidermin.val:
            if not self.closedmin:
                return
            val = self.slidermin.val

        if self.slidermax is not None and val >= self.slidermax.val:
            if not self.closedmax:
                return
            val = self.slidermax.val

        self.set_val(val)

    def set_val(self, val):
        xy = self.poly.xy
        xy[1] = 0, val
        xy[2] = 1, val
        self.poly.xy = xy
        self.valtext.set_text(self.valfmt % val)
        if self.drawon:
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.val = val
        if not self.eventson:
            return
        for cid, func in six.iteritems(self.observers):
            func(val)

    def on_changed(self, func):
        """
        When the slider value is changed, call *func* with the new
        slider position

        A connection id is returned which can be used to disconnect
        """
        cid = self.cnt
        self.observers[cid] = func
        self.cnt += 1
        return cid

    def disconnect(self, cid):
        """remove the observer with connection id *cid*"""
        try:
            del self.observers[cid]
        except KeyError:
            pass

    def reset(self):
        """reset the slider to the initial value if needed"""
        if (self.val != self.valinit):
            self.set_val(self.valinit)
```

Comment: In the `set_val` method, I had to change: `for cid, func in self.observers.iteritems():` with  `for cid, func in six.iteritems(self.observers):` and  `self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()` with `self.ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()`

Comment: Indeed, this was only written to be compatible with Python 2 not 3. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Is there a way to easily emulate `valstep` with this class?