# why is plot not updated with new values correctly under some conditions

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
# MODULE WHICH BEHAVES LIKE SLIDER MODULE BORROWED FROM FOLLOWING ANSWER:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934279/add-a-vertical-slider-with-matplotlib
from vertical_slider_module import VertSlider
########################################
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
amplitude_initial = 5
frequency_initial = 3
########################################
# min_factor, max_factor, initial_value
amplitude_factor = (0.1, 10.0, amplitude_initial)
frequency_factor = (0.1, 10.0, frequency_initial)
phase_factor     = (-np.pi/4, np.pi/4)
vshift_factor    = (0.1, 10.0)
########################################
w1 = amplitude_factor[2]*np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency_factor[2]*t)
w2 = amplitude_factor[2]*np.cos(2*np.pi*frequency_factor[2]*t)
wsum = w1 + w2
########################################
plt.close('all')
# fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, sharex=True)
########################################
line0, = ax[0].plot(t,w1,   lw=2, color='red',   label="red")
line1, = ax[1].plot(t,w2,   lw=2, color='green', label="green")
line2, = ax[2].plot(t,wsum, lw=2, color='blue',  label="blue")
########################################
ax[0].set_xlim([0, 1])
ax[0].set_ylim([-amplitude_factor[1], amplitude_factor[1]])

ax[1].set_xlim([0, 1])
ax[1].set_ylim([-amplitude_factor[1], amplitude_factor[1]])

# ADJUST POSITION
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.5)

# SET GRID FOR ALL SUBPLOTS
max = ax[0].get_xticks()[-1]
xticks_doubled = np.linspace(0,max,num=11)
for (x,y) in np.ndenumerate(ax):
  y.grid()
  y.set_xticks(xticks_doubled)
########################################
# A = 1     # amplitude
# D = 0     # vertical_shift
# B = x_max # frequency
# C = 0     # phase

# SET SLIDER POSITION PARAMETERS
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
left   = 0.05
bottom = 0.14
width  = 0.01
height = fig.get_size_inches()[1] * 0.1 # Q: DIFFERENT SCALE
hgap   = 0.02

# plt.axes([left, bottom, width, height], axisbg=axcolor)
ax_w1_A = plt.axes([left+0*(width+hgap), bottom, width, height], axisbg=axcolor)
ax_w1_B = plt.axes([left+1*(width+hgap), bottom, width, height], axisbg=axcolor)
ax_w1_C = plt.axes([left+2*(width+hgap), bottom, width, height], axisbg=axcolor)
ax_w1_D = plt.axes([left+3*(width+hgap), bottom, width, height], axisbg=axcolor)

vs_w1_A = VertSlider(ax_w1_A, 'w1_A', amplitude_factor[0], amplitude_factor[1], valinit=amplitude_factor[2])
vs_w1_B = VertSlider(ax_w1_B, 'w1_B', frequency_factor[0], frequency_factor[1], valinit=frequency_factor[2])
vs_w1_C = VertSlider(ax_w1_C, 'w1_C', phase_factor[0],     phase_factor[1])
vs_w1_D = VertSlider(ax_w1_D, 'w1_D', vshift_factor[0],    vshift_factor[1])

ax_w2_A = plt.axes([left+4*(width+hgap), bottom, width, height], axisbg=axcolor)
ax_w2_B = plt.axes([left+5*(width+hgap), bottom, width, height], axisbg=axcolor)
ax_w2_C = plt.axes([left+6*(width+hgap), bottom, width, height], axisbg=axcolor)
ax_w2_D = plt.axes([left+7*(width+hgap), bottom, width, height], axisbg=axcolor)

vs_w2_A = VertSlider(ax_w2_A, 'w2_A', amplitude_factor[0], amplitude_factor[1], valinit=amplitude_factor[2])
vs_w2_B = VertSlider(ax_w2_B, 'w2_B', frequency_factor[0], frequency_factor[1], valinit=frequency_factor[2])
vs_w2_C = VertSlider(ax_w2_C, 'w2_C', phase_factor[0],     phase_factor[1])
vs_w2_D = VertSlider(ax_w2_D, 'w2_D', vshift_factor[0],    vshift_factor[1])
########################################
def w1_update(val):

  global w1
  # global wsum
  A = vs_w1_A.val
  B = vs_w1_B.val

  w1 = A*np.sin(2*np.pi*B*t)
  line0.set_ydata(w1)

  wsum = w1 + w2
  line2.set_ydata(wsum)

  ax[2].relim()
  ax[2].autoscale_view()

  print w1[50]
  print w2[50]
  print "#############"

vs_w1_A.on_changed(w1_update)
vs_w1_B.on_changed(w1_update)


def w2_update(val):

  global w2
  # global wsum
  A = vs_w2_A.val
  B = vs_w2_B.val

  w2 = A*np.cos(2*np.pi*B*t)
  line1.set_ydata(w2)

  wsum = w1 + w2
  line2.set_ydata(wsum)

  ax[2].relim()
  ax[2].autoscale_view()

  print w1[50]
  print w2[50]
  print "#############"

vs_w2_A.on_changed(w2_update)
vs_w2_B.on_changed(w2_update)
########################################
plt.show()
```

This code creates three plots. 3rd plot is the sum of 1st and 2nd plot. Parameters for 1st and 2nd plot can be modified via sliders. Plots are changed dynamically when given parameter is modified via slider. Here is the list of parameters (C and D are not implemented yet):

- A = amplitude
- B = frequency
- C = horizontal shift (phase)
- D = vertical shift

Here is the problem; sometimes when I modify the values via slider it seems that the plots are not updated correctly. It seems like `matplotlib` bug for me because when I save the plot via ctr+s and check it, then values are correct. Here are some pictures which explains what I mean:

Following picture was taken by print screen button. As you can see on the slider is set amplitude for 2nd plot to 8.27 (w2_A) but it is obvious from the figure that the amplitude remains on value 5:
[image]

Here is the same picture but after it was saved using ctrl+s. Here the values are correct:
[image]

After slight change (w2_B) the plot has correct values, print screen version:
[image]

"ctrl+s" version:
[image]

I've also noticed that when I click on C and D sliders it sometimes slightly modifies the wave. For those sliders there are no update functions registered, why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change the lines in your callback functions, but you don't tell matplotlib to redraw to the figure. Add this line to the end of your callback functions:

```
fig.canvas.draw()
```

and your plot should get updated as expected.

Comment: Thank you. Two questions: 1st: If I didn't tell `matplotlib` to redraw to the figure, then how is possible that e.g. 1st plot was redrawed? 2nd: Is it the general rule to place `fig.canvas.draw()` at the end of callback function when the function is supposed to modify the plot somehow?